# QTcpServer::hadPendingConnections() returns false upon new connection

Tags: qt, qtcpserver

I am working on some server application, which skeleton is subclassed `QTcpServer`, named `UeTcpServer`. The server app starts normally and when I place breakpoint in `ueSlotTcpServerNewConnection()`, which is connected to `UeTcpServer`'s `newConnectionSignal` via

```
connect(this->ueTcpServer(),
        SIGNAL(newConnection()),
        this,
        SLOT(ueSlotTcpServerNewConnection()));
```

and then connect to server app using `Linux terminal`, breakpoint activates inside `ueSlotTcpServerNewConnection()` slot:

```
void UeMainWindow::ueSlotTcpServerNewConnection()
{
    if(this->ueTcpServer()->hasPendingConnections())
    {
        QTcpSocket* incomingSocket=this->ueTcpServer()->nextPendingConnection();

        this->ueSlotAddEventInfoLog(0,
                                    tr("New incoming connection from host")
                                    .append(" ")
                                    //.append(this->ueTcpServer()->nextPendingConnection()->peerAddress().toString())
                                    .append(incomingSocket->peerName())
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(tr("with IP address"))
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(incomingSocket->peerAddress().toString())
                                    .append(" ")
                                    .append(tr("using port"))
                                    .append(" ")
                                    //.append(this->ueTcpServer()->nextPendingConnection()->peerPort()));
                                    .append(QString::number(incomingSocket->peerPort())));
    }   // if
}   // ueSlotTcpServerNewConnection
```

However, `this->ueTcpServer()->hasPendingConnection()` returns `false`. Why?

Comment: Having looked at my own usage of `QTcpServer` I tend to use `while (QTcpSocket *conn = server->nextPendingConnection()) {` and have never had any problems.  So my question is... when `hasPendingConnections` returns false does `nextPendingConnection` return NULL/nullptr -- or does it actually return a valid connection?

Comment: @G.M. if I remove/comment `if(this->ueTcpServer()->hasPendingConnections())`, I get `NULL` pointer to `QTcpSocket`.

Comment: Did you reimplement incomingConnection in your subclass of QTcpServer in your application. If so, maybe you forget to call addPendingConnection.

Comment: That was it! I've forgot to call `addPendingConnection(QTcpSocket* socket)` from `incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)`. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot to call `addPendingConnection(QTcpSocket *socket` from `incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)` as is also stated in the the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection):

```
void UeTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{  
    QTcpSocket* newSocket=new QTcpSocket(this);

    newSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

    this->addPendingConnection(newSocket);
}   // incomingConnection
```

and it works now.

Comment: you don't need to override `incomingConnection` if this all what you want to do, as this is exactly what the [base implementation](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/network/socket/qtcpserver.cpp#n579) does.

Comment: Why `Q_UNUSED` if you use the function parameter...?